# Sms Integration in opencart store

Tags: opencart, sms-gateway

Im working on SMS integration for Opencart I have purchased SMS's from a company. Now I have API like this :

> http://smst.abcd.co.in/submitsms.jsp?user=ABCDEF&key=12c7ca6975XX&mobile=+911234567890&message=test%20sms&senderid=ABCDEF&accusage=1

Im looking for some extension where i would able to put this integration, if anybody have any ideas, please let me know. thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a library for SMS gateway and place it in your system/library folder..

```
class SendSMS{

    public $user = 'ABCDEF';
    public $key = '12c7ca6975XX';

    public function send($mobile,$message,$senderid,$accusage) {

            $service_url = 'http://smst.abcd.co.in/submitsms.jsp?user=' . $user . '&key=' . $key . '&mobile=' . $mobile . '&message=' . $message . '&senderid=' . $senderid . '&accusage=' . $accusage;

            $curlObj = curl_init($service_url);

            curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $response = curl_exec($curlObj);

            curl_close($curlObj);

            if($response === false) {
                return 'failed';
            } else {
                return 'success';
            }
    }
}
```

Then call this library function from your controller..

```
$sms = new SendSMS();
$sms->send('+911234567890','test%20sms','ABCDEF',1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother, what does mean by "Create a library for SMS gateway" ? means a page you talking about? and I want like if anybody will place the order then the message should go to the customer.. are you a developer? would you able to make the extension for it? or do you have any extension? I will pay you for that if it is very useful.. Im in a big trouble, please reply. thanks